# error CS0117: `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes' does not contain a definition for `Role'

Tags: c#, mono, claims-based-identity

I was trying to build a solution in Travis CI for mono version 3.6.0.
I am using System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes in my project but unfortunately
got this error:

> 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes' does not contain a
>   definition for `Role'

But as I can see in [the source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Claims/ClaimTypes.cs) of mono everything is fine.
I tried to build manually in Elementary OS with apt-get install
mono-complete with latest 3.6.0 version, but got the same error.

At Travis CI I am using [this package](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.6.0/macos-10-x86/MonoFramework-MDK-3.6.0.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg).

Am I missing something?

Comment: You may not target .NET 4.5, note `#if NET_4_5`.

Comment: This directive is using only when mono is building, I am using mono binaries, not compiling it from source code (But maybe should try it :) ).

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Didn't use Mono for a while, don't remember how they ship binaries now days. One of the reasons Role to be missing it wasn't included due targeting 4.0. Other reasons? Hmm, don't know.

Comment: The one strange thing is what I am using ClaimTypes.Name also, and only Role cause this error.

Comment: Can you open the assembly by a tool like Reflector to see what is actually inside it and what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a bunch of entries, including `Role`, have been [added recently](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/c1a76023943fbb32286ea22d69579e57e02fcec7). Although chronologically before `3.6.0` but that release has been made from a separate branch, so it does not contain the relevant commit. You can check the released version of [ClaimTypes.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/f540f8ac339f7e833398c21516dd91dfc9b0dca5/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Claims/ClaimTypes.cs) and see that indeed it does not contain `Role`. You will have to wait for a new release or compile mono yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I also tried [mono-snapshot version from CI package](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ci-packages/), and it is working perfectly.